# POST failed via Postman API to Laravel migrations database

Tags: postman, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-api

GET is working, but POST does not. This is because it fails via Postman API to the Laravel migrations database.

```
function add_user(Request $request)
{
    $user = new user_a;
    csrf_token();
    $user->user_name = $request->user_name;
    $user->password = $request->password;

    $res = $user->save;
    if ($res) {
        return ["operationn" => "Done"];
    } else {
        return ["operation" => "failed_404"];
    }
}
```

**in API file:**

```
Route::post('registeruser',[dynamic_small_controller::class,'add_user']);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send the password in integer format so it is not accepting try with giving password also in ""

```
{
   "user_name":"yahay",
   "password":"8888"
}
```